# Is my method of integration correct?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have integrated $\sin 2x$ using a different method. But the answer is wrong. I want to know what's wrong with the method. You can see that whatever I have done makes sense.

$\sin 2x / 2x$ is 1 due to the property that $\sin \theta / \theta$ is 1.

[image]

Comment: How does $ \ \sin (2n) \ $ get canceled out?  It is a function of $ \ n \ . $  If you are applying the limit of $ \ \frac{\sin (2n)}{2n} \ = \ 1 \ $ as $ \ n \ \rightarrow \ 0 \ \ , $ that has no relevance to integration.  You need to use the substitution $ \ u \ = \ 2n \ , \ dn \ = \frac12 · du \ \   $ and integrate $ \ \int \ \frac12 · \sin u \ \ du  \ \ . $

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Oh. Thanks a lot for the answers. I got it now.

Comment: I see that you felt the wrath of physics ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was pointed out, the equality $\frac{\sin 2x}{2x} = 1$ does not hold. at best, if you were computing definite integrals instead of primitives, your "method" might be used to get an approximated value. For instance, you could say that, for small $b$,
$$
\int_0^b \sin (2x) dx \approx \int_0^b 2x\, dx = b^2
$$
For $b = 0.1$ we get
$$
\int_0^b \sin 2x \, dx = 0.00996671, \qquad b^2 = 0.001
$$

Answer (score 4):

The incorrect reasoning is that ${\frac{\sin(2x)}{2x} = 1}$.

It definitely is true that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1
$$
**but this is a limit**. Indeed though, for small values of $x$, ${\sin(x)\approx x}.$